# BizTalk sends infinite copies to destination folder

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have an orchestration which sends a message A to message box. Now I have 2 subscriber orchestrations which subscribe to the message based on a filter expressions.

Now when I send a message which is to be routed to Subscriber 1, everything works fine, but when a message for subscriber 2 is sent it is routed to destination folder but **infinite copies are created in the destination folder**. I have to stop the orchestration to stop the generation of duplicate copies of message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often a symptom of a feedback loop, i.e. where you have a situation like:

- Implementing a receive port which listens to the location that a send port publishes messages.
- Implementing a direct-bound orchestration with a send port configured to publish messages to the message box of the same schema that it receives (without any filtering)

This is especially common in direct bound (`MessageBox`) scenarios, as this doesn't have the additional filters which are applied with `Specify Now / Later` settings. The solution is usually to add an additional filter - either out of the box, such as [`BTS.ReceivePortName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa562116.aspx), or a custom context property) on subscribers, so that you can distinguish between messages which have already been processed.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
 My send port is not publishing the messages of same schema that are received by the receive port.I have provided a map in which I have mapped ReceiveMsg schema to PublishMessage schema. Then why infinite copies are generated?

Answer (score 2):

Are you receiving the same message that you are sending?  If so this will cause an infinite loop because your receive location will pick the message up when it is sent.  You need to change the filter on the receive, set a flag in your message in the orchestration and then filter on that perhaps.

Comment: Sorry I am  very new to biztalk .Please explain what is meant by setting a flag in the orchestration?

Comment: I usually promote a property in the message, and change the value in the orchestration.  You can then filter on this promoted property to exclude messages that have already passed through your process.